# Where is my import statement pointing to?

Tags: python, importerror

I'm working on a project with the following directory structure:

```
.
├── main.py
└── modules
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── error
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── friendly_error.py
    └── search
        ├── __init__.py
        └── cog.py       <== The "problem child"
```

(Non relevant files omitted for brevity)

When running `main.py`, I get hit with an error in `modules/search/cog.py`:
`No module named 'error'`

This is the import statement in `cog.py` causing the error:

```py
from error.friendly_error import FriendlyError
```

My twofold question is:

- How can I structure the import statement to direct python to the correct file?
- Where is python looking, given the current import statement?

It's worth noting that VSCode does not have an issue with the import statements, and when I click on *Go to definition* of `FriendlyError` it opens up `./modules/error/friendly_error.py`.

Comment: If you `print(sys.path)`, you will see the full list of directories that Python searches for module imports.  This is based on the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, with a few extra paths added by the interpreter.

Comment: Shouldn't files in the working directory be included also?

Comment: Not the working directory, but the directory that contains the entry point for the script.  In your example, that is presumably the directory that contains `main.py`.  Which would mean you would need to use `from modules.error.friendly_error import FriendlyError`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by replacing the import with this:

```py
from ..error.friendly_error import FriendlyError
```

I am still curious to know why this worked and the other one didn't.

Comment: This one works because it's a valid relative import, as long as `modules` is a package. An absolute import `from error.friendly_error` requires `error` to be on the module search path.